# Feature 'FOREIGN (non-SHARD) key to a sharded table' is not supported by SingleStore

Tags: singlestore

I try to create a table with a foreign key to a reference table in SingleStore MemSQL:

```
-- Create table
create rowstore reference table DEPT
(
 deptno INT(2) not null,
 dname VARCHAR(14),
 loc VARCHAR(13),
 constraint PK_DEPT primary key (DEPTNO)
); 

create rowstore table EMP
(
 empno INT(4) not null,
 ename VARCHAR(10),
 job  VARCHAR(9),
 mgr  INT(4),
 hiredate DATE,
 sal  decimal(7,2),
 comm  decimal(7,2),
 deptno INT(2),
 constraint PK_EMP primary key (EMPNO)
 ,constraint FK_DEPTNO foreign key (DEPTNO) references DEPT (DEPTNO)
);
```

but this fails with:

```
ERROR 1706 ER_MEMSQL_FEATURE_LOCKDOWN: Feature 'FOREIGN (non-SHARD) key to a sharded table' is not supported by SingleStore.
```

The message says that the opposite is not possible (foreign key to a shared table) but here I try to create a foreign key from a sharded table to a reference table. This should be possible even when distributed transactions are not supported because it is a single-shard verification.

Answer (score 1):

Foreign Key is not currently a supported feature on SingleStoreDB.

https://docs.singlestore.com/managed-service/en/developer-resources/unsupported-mysql-features/unsupported-feature-list.html